# Why does capturing named groups in Ruby result in "undefined local variable or method" errors?

Tags: ruby, regex, exception, capture

I am having trouble with named captures in regular expressions in Ruby 2.0. I have a string variable and an interpolated regular expression:

```
str = "hello world"
re = /\w+/
/(?<greeting>#{re})/ =~ str
greeting
```

It raises the following exception:

> prova.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`greeting' for main:Object (NameError)
>   shell returned 1

However, the interpolated expression works without named captures. For example:

```
/(#{re})/ =~ str
$1
# => "hello"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Named Captures Must Use Literals

You are encountering some limitations of Ruby's regular expression library. The [Regexp#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) method limits named captures as follows:

- The assignment does not occur if the regexp is not a literal.
- A regexp interpolation, `#{}`, also disables the assignment.
- The assignment does not occur if the regexp is placed on the right hand side.

You'll need to decide whether you want named captures or interpolation in your regular expressions. You currently cannot have both.

Comment: As @ChrisHeald suggested i tried with this:


irb(main):016:0> matches = "hello world".match(/(?<greeting>#{re})/) 


=> #<MatchData "hello" greeting:"hello">


irb(main):017:0> matches[:greeting]


=> "hello"



and it works

Comment: @giuseta Different methods altogether. Also, note that you still aren't assigning to a local variable when you use [MatchData](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html); you're just creating an index into an array. In both cases, the *greeting* variable remains undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the result of `#match`; this will be accessible as a hash that allows you to look up your named capture groups:

```
> matches = "hello world".match(/(?<greeting>\w+)/)
=> #<MatchData "hello" greeting:"hello">
> matches[:greeting]
=> "hello"
```

Alternately, give `#match` a block, which will receive the match results:

```
> "hello world".match(/(?<greeting>\w+)/) {|matches| matches[:greeting] }
=> "hello"
```

Comment: it works thanks :), but I still can't explain myself the cause of that strange behaviour

Comment: match doesn't create new variables, it returns a hash with the key names being the named matches.  so when you tried to access `greeting` it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to both answers in order to make it crystal clear:

```
str = "hello world"
# => "hello world"
re = /\w+/
# => /\w+/
re2 = /(?<greeting>#{re})/
# => /(?<greeting>(?-mix:\w+))/
md = re2.match str
# => #<MatchData "hello" greeting:"hello">
md[:greeting]
# => "hello"
```

Interpolation is fine with named captures, just use the MatchData object, most easily returned via `match`.