# Save multiple regex buffers in variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

In Perl I can do the below and get the expected output `admin1secretpw`.

How do I do the same in Ruby? I.e. save multiple buffers in variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $a = 'admin1:secretpw@example.com';

(my $u = $1, my $p = $2) if $a =~ /(.*?):(.*?)@/;

print $u;
print $p;
```

Comment: Can you ask the question in such a way that a knowledge of Perl is not required to answer the question? Even though I don't know Perl I think I might know what you're trying to do, so I don't think it should be all that difficult to state your question in non-Perl terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use named capture groups.

```
a = 'admin1:secretpw@example.com'     
/(?<username>.*?):(?<password>.*?)@/ =~ a

puts username
puts password
```

This captures both groups as local variables.

The order of arguments to `=~` matters. Using `... =~ a` assigns the named groups to local variables, using `a =~ ...` won't.

Comment: When I pate your code in a file I get ``<main>': no implicit conversion of URI::Generic into String (TypeError)`.

Comment: Works in an empty file. Maybe your code needs `... =~ a.to_s` because in your case `a` is a url rather than a string?

Comment: I see. That solved it =) About your note about `=~`. I don't quite understand how the variables can be local given that I the code snippet isn't inside brackets.

Comment: You mean because the code is not inside a function? Technically all top-level variables in a file are local variables of `<main>`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I would probably need an a/b example to see the difference...  Does there exist such an example that shows the difference of what happens when moving `=~`?

Comment: Oh, they are literally undefined. The named captures work if and only if the regex is on the lefthand side, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890729/why-does-capturing-named-groups-in-ruby-result-in-undefined-local-variable-or-m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131382/discussion-between-jasmine-lognnes-and-akuhn).

Comment: This answer tolerates possibly undefined behavior in the question. Please address that.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the end for an important note on Perl code. With Ruby you can do

```
u, v = a.match(/(.*?):(.*?)@/)[1,2]
```

Here [String#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-match) is used. It recongizes `/.../` as a regex, converts it to a [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Regexp.html) object, and then invokes [Regexp's match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Regexp.html#method-i-match) method on it. That returns a [MatchData](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/MatchData.html) object, which acts as an array. Indexing with `0` gives the whole matched string while `1,2...` access array elements.

If a match fails `nil` is returned so you can test for that, by `if u.nil?` from [NilClass](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html).

An altogether cleaner way may be

```
if matched = a.match(/(.*?):(.*?)@/)
    u, v = matched.captures
end
```

which uses [MatchData#captures](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) method.  Or, you can use `$1` and `$2` inside the block.

Note that any code that defines symbols via regex matches on external data needs to test them.

There are other ways to do this in Ruby. As a curious example, you can do

```
u, v = (/(.*?):(.*?)@/).match(a)[1,2]
```

Here `/.../` constructs a `Regexp` object and then its `match` method is invoked.

This can also be done nicely without regex, using [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-split)

```
u, v = a.split(/:|@/)[0..1]
```

The string `a` is split using *either* `:` *or* `@` as a delimiter.

---

The question is stated with Perl code in a way that needs to be cleared up.

It appears that you intend to declare and assign conditionally. A statement such as `my $x = 1` executes in two parts -- the *declaration* happens at compile time, while the *assignment* goes at runtime. Or, with that condition, it may not.

So, if the assignment *doesn't happen at all* ... then what value do we have? Also, the condition formally implies that the declaration may not happen at all<sup>†</sup>, which is impossible (the declaration *does* happen at compile time, before the `if` is even considered); this makes the whole statement broken in a sense.

From [Statement Modifiers in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) (original emphasis)

> **NOTE:** The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...` ) is **undefined**. The value of the `my` variable may be `undef`, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

So you do not want to do that in Perl. Besides, regex gives you that for free

```
my ($u, $v) = $var =~ /(.*?):(.*?)@/;
```

Now test `$u` and `$v`.  You can also do that in the same statement, if you wish

```
if ( my ($u, $v) = $var =~ /(.*?):(.*?)@/ ) { 
    print "$u, $v\n";
}
```

The condition is true only if both `$u` and `$v` are true.  This may be very handy since `$u` and `$v` are now scoped in a convenient way but it can also be tricky if the regex can match *and* leave a variable(s) falsey, so use with care.

---

<sup>†</sup> That would be processed in the sense of `( my $var = ... )  if ...`

Comment: You are not answering the question. Please use comments for comments.

Comment: @akuhn I had considered before posting and I disagree with that assessment, in _this case_.  They are asking for code equivalent to something potentially dangerous in Perl.  This needs to be raised, and prominently. It doesn't fit in a comment.  Your answer _did not_ point it out.

Comment: @Jasmine Lognnes  I updated this post considerably, now also directly answering the question.  You got your answer, which is great, but you may want to see this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Perl, so I'm just guessing you want to do the following in Ruby.

```
a = 'admin1:secretpw@example.com'

a =~ /(.*?):(.*?)@/
($1 && $2) ? (u, v = $1, $2) : nil
  #=> ["admin1", "secretpw"] 
u #=> "admin1" 
v #=> "secretpw" 

a = 'admin1?secretpw@example.com'

a =~ /(.*?):(.*?)@/
($1 && $2) ? (u, v = $1, $2) : nil
  #=> nil
```

`a`, `u` and `p` are local variables. `@a`, `@u` and `@p` would be *instance variables* and `$a`, `$u` and `$p` would be *global variables*.

The asker obviously knows what the regex does, so I don't need to say anything about that.

Here are a couple other ways you could do that in Ruby.

```
a = 'admin1:secretpw@example.com'

rv = a.scan(/.+(?=:)|(?<=:).+?(?=@)/).flatten
  #=> ["admin1", "secretpw"]
rv.size == 2 ? (u, v = rv) : nil
  #=> ["admin1", "secretpw"] 
u #=> "admin1" 
v #=> "secretpw"
```

and

```
rv = a.split(/[:\@]/).take(2)
  #=> ["admin1", "secretpw"] 
rv.size == 2 ? (u, v = rv) : nil
  #=> ["admin1", "secretpw"]
```

See [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split).